# how to write sin squared in java

Tags: java, trigonometry

```
double maxHeight = 0.0;

velocity = v;
angle = theta;

maxHeight = Math.pow(velocity, 2.0);
maxHeight = Math.pow(sin, 2.0);
maxHeight *= Math.sin(angle) / (2 * gravity);
```

I'm trying to get the `Math.pow(sin, 2.0);`. it's asking me to declare `sin`. What am I supposed to put down for it? I'm just trying to get sin squared.

Comment: What does "I'm just trying to get sin squared." mean? What do you want to do? What do you want to calculate?

Comment: I'm trying to use this formula: maximum height attained is h  =  v ^2 sin^ 2 ( θ  ) / ( 2 g  )

Comment: I thought using the Math.pow function works, but it's asking me to declare sin. I don't know what I'm supposed to put down for it, if I declare sin

Comment: Are you sure than "sin" variable exists?

Comment: It doesn't. I'm very new to java as you can tell. I don't know what I'm supposed to define it as.

Comment: You must define "sin" in the same way as you define variable maxHeight to be able to use it as variable.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Hold on.

Comment: Ok, I added some code to my answer.

Comment: @Mac70 it is a *sin* to name a variable `sin`.

Comment: @Mac70 I need help with my homework, is it okay if I can ask it here or no? Stack exchange says I can't ask another question until next week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - Math.pow(x, 2.0) is equal to sin * sin, and the second approach should be much more efficient.

When it comes to answer to your question - does the variable "sin" you want to use in second Math.pow() exists?

Example code:

```
// assuming that "v", "theta" and "gravity" are known variables

double sin = Math.sin(theta);
double maxHeight = (v * v * sin * sin) / (gravity * 2);
```

Corrected original code:

```
double maxHeight = 0.0;

velocity = v;
angle = theta;

maxHeight = Math.pow(velocity, 2.0);
double sin = Math.sin(angle);
maxHeight *= Math.pow(sin, 2.0) / (2 * gravity);
```

Comment: It doesn't exist. What would I put down for it?

Comment: I added code to the answer to make things more clear.

Comment: So you declared sin as a double, and you put the formula down as Math.sin(theta);

Comment: The return of the maxHeight is that whole formula computed?

Comment: sin^2(value) in maths is equal to Java Math.sin(value) * Math.sin(value), which can be simplified by making Math.sin(value) a variable and use it instead of computing the sin two times. Other than that, maxHeight is that formula.

Comment: Mac, thank you. I tested the code in my program and it worked. I really appreciate the answer, friendliness and the clearness. I computed the formula by hand to double check I'm getting the correct answer in the program, and I am! Now I have to figure out the Time of flight portion...

Comment: Mac, can you check this code to see if I did it properly:

Comment: public double timeOfFlight(double v, double theta)
 {
  velocity = v;
  angle = theta;
  
  double sin = Math.sin(theta);
  double flightTime = (2 * v * sin / gravity);
  
  return flightTime;

Comment: What you did is flightTime = (2 * v * sin(theta)) / gravity, compare with original formula.

Comment: I removed the (theta) and just kept sin, since sin is defined. It ran perfect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your current code is that you are trying to access a variable named `sin` but that variable doesn't exist. Since you're starting with Java, let's start over.

You want to calculate `h = v² sin²( θ ) / ( 2 g )`. We already have `v` and `theta`.

First, the numerator is `v² sin²(θ)`. This means we need to calculate `v²`. Then we need to calculate `sin(θ)` and square the result. Then we need to multiply those two number together. Put to code, we have:

```
double vSquared = Math.pow(v, 2);
double sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
double sinThetaSquared = Math.pow(sinTheta, 2);
double numerator = vSquared * sinThetaSquared;
```

The denominator is simply `2*g` so we have:

```
double maxHeight = numerator / (2 * gravity);
```

If we simplify this into a single expression, we come up with:

```
//test data
double v = 1.0;
double theta = 1.5;
double gravity = 9.8;

double maxHeight = Math.pow(v, 2) * Math.pow(Math.sin(theta), 2) / (2 * gravity);
```

Comment: Thank you Tunaki, I appreciate your insight as well.